# Android Dev UI - Text and image widget

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Hi I am new to Android development and I want to add a specific looking view in the my main app window, which I have seen in many apps but dont actually know the name of it :) So its hard for me to check the android developers websites for details.

Below is a good example of an app using this widget or whatever is check the link:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/K7HJq6Be9AVf6EiDc0pviGLNyMJ4CL1f5Bw6HmxDUaQc7vpu18KAxrF6VlG5fJciFF59=h900-rw

Look at the ones that have Squat etc in thats Im referring to. Im not wanting to build a workout app, but I want to use a similar floating area like this, as I like the look. So the question is what is this called in android, its not a listview or textview I believe.

Sorry for the noob question but as I said Im very VERY green at Android dev.

Thanks

Comment: this is CardView with RecyclerView...check material design concept..

Answer (score 0):

The view used here are

1. CardView - [Check](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)
2. Recyclerview -[Check](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)
3. Viewpager with fragments -[Check](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)
4. Toolbar- [Check](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-App-ToolBar)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown for each, ill check those out.